# Can you query the maximum database size based on the SQL Server license?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Depending on the licensing and configuration of your SQL Server database, you may have have very different size restrictions. For example:

- SQL Server 2012 Express       has a limit of 10GB
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Express    has a limit of 10GB
- SQL Server 2008 Express       has a limit of  4GB

Is it possible to **query the database server to find out what the maximum size is**?

I can query to find out the current size:

```
name      DataFileSizeMB LogFileSizeMB  
--------- -------------- -------------  
master          4.875000      1.750000  
tempdb          8.000000      0.500000  
model           4.062500      1.000000  
msdb           16.687500      4.562500  
Harrison       21.937500     18.187500  
Lennon        122.750000    425.625000  
McCartney      19.937500     49.687500  
Starr          19.937500     18.187500
```

What I'm now after, is a way to find out what the maximum is, based on the **licensing** not the available HDD space.

Comment: I tried to include the SQL for this query, but stackoverflow was blocking it for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
      d.server_name
    , d.sversion_name
    , d.edition
    , max_db_size_in_gb = 
        CASE WHEN engine_edition = 4 
            THEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN d.sversion_name LIKE '%2012%' THEN 10
                    WHEN d.sversion_name LIKE '%2008 R2%' THEN 10
                    WHEN d.sversion_name LIKE '%2008%' THEN 4 
                    WHEN d.sversion_name LIKE '%2005%' THEN 4
                END
            ELSE -1 
        END
FROM (
    SELECT 
          sversion_name = SUBSTRING(v.ver, 0, CHARINDEX('-', v.ver) - 1)
        , engine_edition = SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition')
        , edition = SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')
        , server_name = SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')
    FROM (SELECT ver = @@VERSION) v
) d
```

Also, try this query to get extended info about DB -

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects 
    WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#DBObj')
) DROP TABLE #DBObj

CREATE TABLE #DBObj
(
      [DB] SYSNAME
    , reservedpages INT
    , usedpages INT
    , pages INT
)

EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb '
    USE [?]

    INSERT INTO #DBObj
    (
          [DB]
        , reservedpages
        , usedpages
        , pages
    )
    SELECT 
          DB_NAME()
        , pg.reservedpages
        , pg.usedpages
        , pg.pages   
    FROM (
        SELECT
              reservedpages = SUM(a.total_pages)
            , usedpages = SUM(a.used_pages)
            , pages = SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN it.internal_type IN (202, 204, 207, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 221, 222) THEN 0
                    WHEN a.[type] != 1 AND p.index_id < 2 THEN a.used_pages
                    WHEN p.index_id < 2 THEN a.data_pages ELSE 0
                END
              )
        FROM sys.partitions p
        JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.[partition_id] = a.container_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.internal_tables it ON p.[object_id] = it.[object_id]
    ) pg'

SELECT 
      d.name
    , total_size_mb = data.row_size_mb + data.log_size_mb
    , data.log_size_mb
    , data.row_size_mb
    , reserved_space_mb = CAST(do.reservedpages * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
    , data_size_mb = CAST(do.pages * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
    , index_size_mb = CAST((do.usedpages - do.pages) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
    , unused_size_mb = CAST((do.reservedpages - do.usedpages) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
    , unallocated_space_mb = 
        CAST(CASE WHEN data.row_size >= do.reservedpages 
            THEN (data.row_size - do.reservedpages) * 8. / 1024 
            ELSE 0
        END AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM (
    SELECT
          df2.database_id
        , log_size_mb = CAST(df2.log_size * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
        , row_size_mb = CAST(df2.row_size * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) 
        , df2.log_size
        , df2.row_size
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              df.database_id
            , log_size = SUM(CASE WHEN df.type_desc = 'LOG' THEN df.size END)
            , row_size = SUM(CASE WHEN df.type_desc = 'ROWS' THEN df.size END)
        FROM sys.master_files df
        GROUP BY df.database_id 
    ) df2
) data
JOIN sys.databases d ON data.database_id = d.database_id
JOIN #DBObj do ON do.DB = d.name
ORDER BY data.row_size_mb + data.log_size_mb DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, I was contemplating heading this way myself and you've saved me a couple of hours.

Answer (score 2):

I linke Devart's ansatz, but how about something a bit more compact:

```
SELECT max_db_size_in_gb = 
    CASE WHEN serverproperty('EngineEdition') = 4 THEN
        CASE WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') between '10.50' and '5' THEN 10 ELSE 4 END
    ELSE -1 
    END
```

(Instead of parsing the output of @@VERSION, checking SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') is surely easier? Also, this is safer when new versions like SQL Server 2014 are released.)

(Edited: Old version was just checking for "< '10.50'", which of course is wrong since e.g. '9.00' (SQL Server 2005) is lexicographically bigger!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it at a "give me the max size of the database"-level, but you could query [`sys.database_files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397.aspx) and piece it together from the files which make up the database.

I think the relevant column will be `max_size`, which is the max file size in 8KB pages.

**PS.** `sys.database_files` is a per-database view, if you wanted to view it across your entire SQL Server instance then [`sys.master_files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782.aspx) may be better....

Comment: I did look at that, but for the databases I was looking at the value was `-1` which means `File will grow until the disk is full` .

Comment: So what do you call the max size when no max size is set?

Comment: What I'm now after, is a way to find out what the maximum is, based on the *licensing* not the available HDD space.

Answer (score -1):

All sizes reported are in **MB**

Note - there are better ways to check whether a file is a log or data file; checking for ".ldf" suffix here works for 99% of installations.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#sizes') is not null
drop table #sizes;
GO
create table #sizes (dbname sysname, cursize int, maxsize int, isunlimited int, curlogsize int, maxlogsize int, islogunlimited int);

exec sp_msforeachdb '
insert #sizes
select ''?'',
    sum(case when filename like ''%.ldf'' then 0 else size end),
    sum(case when filename like ''%.ldf'' then 0 else maxsize end),
    min(case when filename like ''%.ldf'' then 0 else maxsize end),
    sum(case when filename like ''%.ldf'' then size else 0 end),
    sum(case when filename like ''%.ldf'' then maxsize else 0 end),
    min(case when filename like ''%.ldf'' then maxsize else 0 end)
from [?].sys.sysfiles';

select dbname, cursize / 128.0,
    case when isunlimited = -1 then 'unlimited' else str(maxsize/128.0) end, curlogsize/128.0,
    case when islogunlimited = -1 then 'unlimited' else str(maxlogsize/128.0) end
from #sizes
order by dbname;
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, I'm aware of the `maxsize` field but that's not the limitation I'm trying to find. What I'm after is the limitation that the license imposes on the database size.

Comment: Then simply use `select @@version`. If it contains "EXPRESS", then there is a size limit, otherwise there isn't. If it contains 2005, then it's 4GB, otherwise 10GB.