# Database Usage % of max

Tags: sql-server, max

I want a stored procedure I can execute that gives the % of maximum possible space that a database can take up. For example, `SQL Server 2005/2008` have a 4GB DB limit, and 2008R2 has a 10GB limit (express editions).

I know I can `EXEC sp-spaceused` to get the current database size, and unallocated space, but the unallocated space appears to be of some arbitrary chunk size, and a new chunk will be allocated as the database grows.

Is there a procedure I can call to get the maximum size limit for a DB? Ideally, what I want is a percentage of what's currently allocated vs maximum, so if the DB currently is at 2GB, and I'm on SQL 2008 R2 (10GB max), the procedure would return 20.0, or 0.2 to indicate 20%. Since the DB can be on any  number of different SQL Server installations, I do not want to assume a SQL server version and would like to get the max value at runtime.

Comment: But this only really applies to Express Edition.  How many express edition versions are there with different Max values? Your SP could just check the version number, and return the correct value.

Comment: Are you saying that only Express Editions have a max DB size? And full versions are not restricted?

Comment: For practical purposes yes.  The max db size for SQLServer 2008 is over 500 TB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you query the maximum database size based on the SQL Server license?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960241/can-you-query-the-maximum-database-size-based-on-the-sql-server-license)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT @@version` and parse the version and edition out of that string.  You'd have to compare that against a manually populated data set that has the maximum storage allowed for the particular SQL version/edition.

Something like this should get that info out of the version string

```
DECLARE @VersionString VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @Product VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Edition VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @VersionString = @@VERSION
SET @Product = SUBSTRING(@VersionString, 0, PATINDEX('%-%', @VersionString))
SET @Edition = SUBSTRING(@VersionString, PATINDEX('%Corp%', @VersionString) + 13 , 18)
SELECT @Product
SELECT @Edition
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, in the non-Express versions, there are no particular limitations by database size. Therefore, the size of the database is limited only by the capacity of your HDD. So, try this one -

```
SELECT 
      d.server_name
    , d.sversion_name
    , d.edition
    , max_db_size_in_gb = 
        CASE WHEN engine_edition = 4 
            THEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN d.sversion_name LIKE '%2012%' THEN 10
                    WHEN d.sversion_name LIKE '%2008 R2%' THEN 10
                    WHEN d.sversion_name LIKE '%2008%' THEN 4 
                    WHEN d.sversion_name LIKE '%2005%' THEN 4
                END
            ELSE -1 
        END
FROM (
    SELECT 
          sversion_name = SUBSTRING(v.ver, 0, CHARINDEX('-', v.ver) - 1)
        , engine_edition = SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition')
        , edition = SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')
        , server_name = SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')
    FROM (SELECT ver = @@VERSION) v
) d
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960241/can-you-query-the-maximum-database-size-based-on-the-sql-server-license